# Is there a container that takes shape of an image or icon?

Tags: java, swing

I have an ImageIcon which is an image of a router. I added this ImageIcon to a label. But labels are either rectangles or squares. I want such a component that takes the shape of the ImageIcon when added to it. Does such a component exist? Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "takes the shape of the ImageIcon"? Do you just want something that will allow mouse clicks to pass through if they're not on the image?

Comment: yes provide more details

Comment: Isn't the image itself a rectangle.  It may not appear that way because of transparency.  Technically you could have a very large image in size with a very small viewable picture due to the transparent area being large.  (ex:  16x16px image saved on a 8x11inch image 'page')

Answer (score 1):

Yes label is rectangular but it is transparent by default( call `setOpaque( false )` if it isn't ). Isn't that what you want?